# .htaccess How to redirect multiple pages from one section to another section?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've read many answers but keep getting 500 server errors so I'm obviously missing something simple.

The `food-travel` section has changed to `/blog/` and I simply need to redirect all pages under `/food-travel/` to `/blog/`

I've tried many variations but this is what I have currently:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/food-travel[/]?(.*) ^/blog[/]?(.*)
```

What am I missing? Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have existing directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to take a look into your http servers error log file for a more precise error message than "status 500". But even like this some things should be changed in your rule. It seems that you did not consider taking a look into the documentation of the `RedirectMatch` directive. Have a look over here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch

Most likely this is close to what you are looking for:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/food-travel/?(.*)$ /blog/$1
```

Comment: Well, I did look at apache help pages and have re-read the page you link to and still don't understand sorry. While I'm sure this is all obvious to people who know, some of this stuff makes no sense to me. However, now I have an answer that works, I can lookup the things I was missing and understand what the problem was. Cheers

Comment: Ok, glad I could be of help. And don't worry, we all learn all the time, in general for all of us there is much more stuff we do _not_ know than stuff we _do_ know ;-) Where you generally went wrong simply is this: such a rule has 4 tokens: the directive `RedirectMatch`, the http code (301), a matching pattern and a target. Pattern and target follow different rules: the pattern is a "regular expression" (learn about them!) and the target is a path with placeholders ("variables"). You used something like a regular expression for both, which won't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Using RewriteRule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^food-travel/(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

or using RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/food-travel/(.*)$ /blog/$1
```